# Looking for good conference this summer for homotopy theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, soft-question, conferences

I'm a 2nd year grad student and I'm looking for conferences/summer schools to attend this summer.  I checked out the AMS calendar but couldn't find anything I found relevant there. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As I commented below, you may want to join the Topology list serv, they often talk about conferences. Another place to keep an eye on in the N-category cafe, however they have a slant of the type of conferences in topology they are interested in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "no longer relevant".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Georgia Topology Conference will be largely focused on a geometric end of algebraic topology this year. As least, that what I suspect. The homotopy-type of embeddings of smooth manifolds, Goodwillie calculus, configuration spaces, etc, should be a major feature:

http://www.math.uga.edu/~topology/

I think there's a big summer school / conference in Pisa, Italy for much of the summer but I haven't found much information on it on-line.  I suspect it will be oriented towards configuration spaces but I don't know for sure.

Ah, I found a webpage for the Pisa meeting:

http://www.crm.sns.it/hpp/events/event.html?id=121;sez=aims#title

Comment: Is there some other central database besides the AMS calendar, where you are getting this information? Or did you just know about these conferences?

Comment: I heard about this conference through the topology list serve. You can sign up here:https://lists.lehigh.edu/mailman/listinfo/algtop-l

Comment: The UGA one I know about because I'll be going.  Pisa I've heard about from two people who are giving talks.  So I'm planning on being there to talk with them.  I believe the Pisa meeting will include at least the last half of May, maybe a little more. 

Answer (score 4):

Sarah Whitehouse maintains a list of topology conferences at
http://www.sarah-whitehouse.staff.shef.ac.uk/btconfs.html

The Talbot workshops are a great opportunity for PhD students and young researchers (this year's topic: twisted K-theory). I don't know if they still have places available.

I'd also recommend the Young Topologists' Meeting in Copenhagen (June 16-20) and, with a somewhat more focussed and advanced scope, the meeting at the Fields Institute (August 30-Sept 3)